# MYSQL query for updating on multiple duplicate field entry

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Below is the sample tables I'm working on

**Table 1**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ KID║  REV         ║ REDO ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 43453453345  ║  2   ║
║  1 ║ 2433423423   ║  1   ║
║  2 ║ 23423423     ║  1   ║
║  2 ║ 5566533      ║  2   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

I need to insert **REV**, **KID** and **REDO** into **table 1** and while inserting if there is a duplicate entry for both **KID** and **REDO** I need to just update **REV**.
  I tried using **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** but I have two fields which are not primary here.
How to accomplish that with just plain mysql? Please help me

Comment: Use a trigger which updates the rows if the values already exist on insert

Comment: @Zelldon can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a trigger which is triggered before an insert and checks if the KID and REDO id already exists. If they exist it executes an update.

The trigger could look for example like this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET rev = SELECT REV 
              FROM table1 as t 
              WHERE t.KID = NEW.KID 
              AND t.REDO = NEW.REDO;
    IF rev != NEW.REV THEN
     UPDATE table1
     SET REV = NEW.REV 
     WHERE KID = NEW.KID 
     AND REDO = NEW.REDO;
    END IF;
  END;//
delimiter ;
```

But after the update the insert will still happen thats why you should create
a unique index for the REDO and KID. So if you insert a duplicate you get an error and the trigger will nevertheless update the REV.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_table1_idx on table1 (KID, REDO)
```

Another alternative is to send an signal and abort the insert, if the result of the SQL query is not null. Which means the insert will be create an duplicate entry.

```
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'duplicate insert';
```

Comment: I cant change the structure of table,so both the fields are not defined unique.will Trigger work as expected in this case?

Comment: the create index can be added after creation of a table - but you can also add a check if the result of the select query is not null if so a duplicate will be inserted so send an singal to abort the insert signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'duplicate insert';

Comment: @AafreenFirdaus please vote and accept the answer if it fits your needs

Comment: It doesn't help as of now,but I hope it does in the future :) thanks mate!